# Load comment for a picture on windows phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

There are some pictures uploaded by users and others can comment them. It raise a problem that each picture has different number of comments, so I don't know I need to make how many textblocks display in xaml file. Please help me to solve it.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining your text blocks ahead of time in the XAML, use a container control (such as a `ListView`) to databind a display template to an `ObservableCollection` of comment objects.

Take a look at a tutorial like [this one](http://3water.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/tutorial-of-the-day-2-binding-data-to-controls-on-wp7/) to see this kind of databinding in action.